# Cronjob for CiviCRM with drush 10: The "-u" option does not exist

Tags: cron, cron-job, scheduled-job

According to this documentation https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#drush I defined the following crontab:

```
* * * * * /var/www/path_to_civi_project/vendor/drush/drush/drush -u cronuser -r /var/www/path_to_civi_project/httpdocs -l https://www.public-url.org/ civicrm:api job.execute auth=0 -y
```

This leads to an error:

```
The "-u" option does not exist.
```

When I remove this option the Mailings Scheduler fails:

```
Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM
```

As the -u option seems to be removed from newer drush versions I wonder how I get the cronjob working. Do I need cv? Can I add cv with composer?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there still is a way to use drush but I got the cronjob working with cv:

```
composer require civicrm/cv
```

And then the crontab is:

```
* * * * * /var/www/path_to_civi_project/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api job.execute --user=cronuser --cwd=/var/www/path_to_civi_project/httpdocs
```